# Seeing CAPTCHA with noscript in Firefox

Tags: support, anonymous

I am using Tor with Firefox, and I don't want my identity to be exposed on a forum.

Now when registering I can't see the CAPTCHA with no-script.
Is there a way to see it without exposing my IP or identity?

Answer (score 2):

I believe reCAPTCHA has a [fallback system](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/faq#no_js) in place when the user does not have JavaScript enabled. That could possibly be used if it isn't already.